# Running Django management command from tests?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django management command to create materialized views on my database, that runs as follows (I store my database login details in environment variables):

```
python manage.py create_db_matviews $DB_NAME $DB_USER $DB_PASS
```

The management command code looks like this:

```
 class Command(BaseCommand):
   def handle(self, *args, **options):
    db_name = args[0]
    db_user = args[1]
    db_pass = args[2]
    self.conn = psycopg2.connect(database=db_name, user=db_user,
                                 password=db_pass)
```

Now I want to run the management command from inside my tests, so that the materialized views get created on my test data. However this does not work:

```
def setUpModule():
    # load fixtures, then... 
    management.call_command('create_db_matviews',
                        ['test', 'test', 'test'], verbosity=0)
```

It fails as follows:

```
.... 
db_user = args[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

How can I supply arguments to the management script in the way that it wants?

Also, what credentials should I use to get access to the test database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because in tuple of args You set only one argument, with is list of 3 values. You should use:

```
management.call_command('create_db_matviews', 'test', 'test', 'test', verbosity=0)
```

`*agrs` is pythons way to send multiple parameters and all of them will be send as tuple. You send `(['test', 'test', 'test', ],)`
so `args[0]` was `['test', 'test', 'test', ]`, not `'test'`